# GWT div aria-hidden not hiding in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gwt, accessibility

I programmed my landing page with GWT. In IE I get this empty band at the end of it (I painted it in green so that you can see it):

[image]

This only happens in IE (I'm testing with IE9). Not in Chrome, not in Firefox, not in Safari.

Checking out the DOM, the responsible for this area is the following div:

[image]

For some reason, the "*display:none;*" inline rule is not working. If I uncheck it and check it back again, then the green band disappears!!

But I'm not gonna ask my users to do that each time they load my landing page, so is there a way to get rid of this div (apparently generated by GWT), or to make the inline style "*display:none;*" work??

Thanks!

**Additional explanation**:
I didn't write the aria-hidden HTML divs, they were generated by GWT. I just *observed* that they are responsible for the green band that I want to remove. The observation comes from the fact that when I uncheck the *display:none;* property in the IE DOM viewer and then check it back again, the green band disappears.

Comment: As the other answer notes, `aria-hidden` is only used by screenreaders and other accessibility tools, and has no effect on display or layout. It's typically only used in rare accessibility problem cases. Are you sure that the problem is the display:none div, and isn't, for example, due to a margin on some other element?

Comment: Im having the exact same issue, and what you state is not true for iOS 6. That div actually causes some serious issue. If you go from portrait to landscape and back to portrait all the layout breaks (you get all the screen displaced to the right and a thick blank colunm in the right). I tested this using WEINRE (http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) and if I remove disable the 10cm with from that div, the layout works again.

Answer (score 1):

From what I am understanding about both `aria-hidden` and your question, you may be using the attribute incorrectly. The attribute tells people using screen readers to ignore the content within the element, and should be used in conjunction with `visibility:none`. There was a question about [notifing users about a now visable `div`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349987/how-to-notify-screen-readers-using-wai-aria-that-a-div-is-now-visible) that may be a good read. The author of the accepted answer wrote a [blog post](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/) about it as well.

Comment: I didn't explain myself correctly; I didn't place those divs there (see Additional Explanation in my question). They just seem to be responsible for the green band that I want to remove.

Comment: ARIA support is built into some widgets, you have no control over it, so unless you are adding ARIA roles/states explicitly there is no way to missus the attribute as you state, which by reading the question I don't think is the case.

Comment: @Chepech it was inappropriate to downvote my answer. I answered before the poster tweaked the question. Maybe I didnt see that he edited it. The original question suggested he was using aria-hidden to visually hide something. His original question had *nothing* to do about widgets .

Comment: Interesting move on your part. If it makes you happy to downvote, then so be it, I cannot check every question I answer to see if it was changed. To each their own.