# How to display file sizes in an accessible way in HTML

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm trying to find out how to render file sizes in a way that screenreaders will understand. The visual representation is something like

```
2,540 KiB of 200 MiB
```

but when I try this out in ChromeVox, all it reads out is "of". I'm having great difficulty finding detailed documentation of which kinds of text are read out and which aren't, and how I should structure the text so that it will be read out.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26032207/5962802

Comment: What's the HTML structure around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you label your sizes using standard abbreviations, such as 200MB or 1.2GB, then screen reader users are used to hearing sizes read as initials.  If you want to go beyond that, then you can have an aria-label that has the full pronunciation, such as "200 megabytes" or "1.2 gigabytes".  The stackoverflow referenced by Ivo shows how to have visually hidden text with an aria-label.