# Adding WAI-ARIA support to jQuery .toggle() method

Tags: jquery, accessibility, wai-aria

I'd like to pair [WAI-ARIA `aria-hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) support with jQuery's .toggle() method.

So given `<p id="myElement">Hi there</p>`

`$('#myElement').toggle()` would hide the element, and set `aria-hidden="true"`:

`<p id="myElement" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">Hi there</p>`

And executing the same `$('#myElement').toggle()` script again would show (toggle) the element, and set (toggle) `aria-hidden="false"`:

`<p id="myElement" style="display: block" aria-hidden="false">Hi there</p>`

I probably want to use the complete function of [the method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), maybe something along the lines of

```
$('#myElement').toggle(
    if ($this.css('display')==='none'){
       $this.prop('aria-hidden', 'true')
    }
    else
    {
            $this.prop('aria-hidden', 'false')
    }
)
```

**What's the most performant solution for extending `.toggle()` to also toggle the `aria-hidden` state?**

Comment: Curious, but why do you want to do this? Screenreaders (and the browser's implementation of the platform's accessibility API) already know that display:none means the element is hidden, so will ignore it anyway. The main reason for using aria-hidden is if content is being hidden in some other way (eg made transparant or put offscreen) so that the browser and screenreaders need to be told explicitly to treat it as hidden.

Comment: Great googily...@BrendanMcK comment prompted me to check some facts. Didn't realize how uninformed I was about ARIA. I'd gotten the idea to pair CSS display characteristics with matching aria-hidden state from http://filamentgroup.com/dwpe/; though in their defense the book was published in 2010, when these details might have worked differently. I now see (from http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/, for example), that it's all about the CSS. So now I question the utility of aria-hidden.

Comment: @BrendanMCK...I could go in two directions with this: 1) accept "don't bother, dummy", or 2) change my question to pair the HTML `hidden` property with `.toggle()`.

Comment: My 2c is that it's fine as-is. The `display:none` idiom is so well established that any viable accessibility tool needs to understand it. In some hypothetical future scenario, HTML5's hidden may be the way to go - it has the advantage of not relying on CSS being on, but even it has some quirks (not supposed to use it to hide tabs, for example). Example of a good use for aria-hidden is when a lightbox pops to the foreground with rest of the page visible but grayed out; aria-hidden can work there as a way of saying "this content is effectively not readable by the user, so treat it as hidden".

Comment: Since someone else might benefit from this journey, I'm going to create an "answer" that notes these details. Then I'm going to create a second question for adding HTML `hidden` property to `.toggle()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer is that there's no need to do so.**

Accessible Technology supports CSS's `display: hidden;` property in a way that already properly hides the element. So specifying `aria-hidden="true"` is redundant, from a screen-reader's point of view, to jQuery's `.toggle()` method setting the `display` property to `hidden`. Specifying `aria-hidden="false"` (or removing the `aria-hidden` property) is redundant to jQuery's `.toggle()` method setting the `display` property to `inline`.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10351673/1430996 and [Steve Faulkner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361227/steve-faulkner)'s [HTML5 Accessibility Chops: hidden and aria-hidden](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/) blog post (particularly the "Results Summary") for further details.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct in spirit, but has some problems in specifics:

1. There is no 'hidden' value for the CSS Display property--it should be 'none'.
2. jQuery .toggle() doesn't set the display to 'inline' when un-hiding; it sets it back to blank, which falls back to whatever value is dictated by the cascade. So if the computed value for display was 'block', that's what it returns to.

Comment: If you see an answer that needs improvement, please feel free to click the 'edit' link below the answer and make the needed changes.  You can leave a comment about what you did, and why, on the Edit screen.  Thanks for helping!