# My JSPerf test case "breaks" while evaluating toggle() with callback

Tags: javascript, jsperf

While testing [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14636007/1430996) to [Adding HTML5 hidden attribute support to jQuery .toggle() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635847/adding-html5-hidden-attribute-support-to-jquery-toggle-method), I created [a JSPerf test to determine how much slower `.toggle(function() \[...\])` would be compared to `.toggle()`](http://jsperf.com/hidden-premium). To my amazement, the script with additional processing is reported to execute faster! Besides the results being counter-intuitive, I suspect a problem because I also see the toggling on the screen long after the results have returned.

**How can I "fix" my test to get accurate results?**

Comment: Added git issue https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsperf.com/issues/115

Comment: Oh gods...the motion sickness! My eyes..! @.@

Comment: @DavidThomas: I know! :) It's practically a `<blink>` tag!

Comment: And I just reopened the page to risk starting the test again and *it's still going..!* I...oh, Lord...that's *evil* (albeit a perfectly valid test-case...) D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I.e.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#myElement').toggle(function() { alert("called") })
})
```

The callback function you pass to `toggle` only gets executed *after* the toggle action completes. In other words, it’s an asynchronous action, so if you want to measure how long it takes until the callback is fired, [use jsPerf’s async/defer feature](http://jsperf.com/faq#async).

Comment: My first attempt to add `deferred.resolve()` (http://jsperf.com/hidden-premium/3) didn't go well, but I think I got it closer with the second attempt (http://jsperf.com/hidden-premium/4). Is that the right way to do my test?