# How to implement invisible but accessible link in a table cell?

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

I'm trying to create a clickable empty table cell that is also accessibility friendly.

Use case: a table of a day's schedule with each cell representing a time slot.  Where there is nothing in the cell, the time slot is available and should be clickable so that the time slot could be booked.

How do I implement this so that it's WCAG2.0 compliant?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of aria hidden, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349987/how-to-notify-screen-readers-using-wai-aria-that-a-div-is-now-visible

Comment: Wouldn't `background-color:transparent` do it? Not sure about the accessibility side.

Comment: You could have a transparent link in the cell. eg http://jsfiddle.net/LZrc5/1/

Comment: @Moob While aesthetically the transparent link works, I tried that table with Chrome Vox and the link descriptions were not read out loud by the screen reader.

Comment: Setting the opacity to 0.001 may overcome this problem. I'm not familiar with Vox but some screen readers will interpret this as visible even though it's too faint to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are specifically thinking of blind people (as most web authors/designers who think about accessibility really are), then you can include e.g. a single-pixel transparent image with a descriptive alt text, say

```
<td><a href=...><img alt=Available src=pixel1.gif width=1 height=1></a></td>
```

with some CSS that makes the `a` element fill the `td` element visually.

But thinking wider, you could start from the question whether all sighted people will immediately understand that a blank cell means availability. Usually, when an empty cell is the problem, the solution consists of making it non-empty, somehow.

Comment: I think this would work if I can just figure out how to make the link fill the cell with CSS.

Comment: A placeholder image solution to a question about web best practises in 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clip property from css

```
.element-invisible { 
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */ 
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    font-size:1%;  /* ios */
}


<td><a class="element-invisible" href=...>bla bla bla</a></td>
```

If you want more information about this technique go to :

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/clip-hidden-content-better-accessibility-53456.html

Comment: Wait, at the link you've provided, it clearly states "if content is ignored in Voice Over with the latest rule above, it is […] because of `overflow:hidden`. So you're making it *inaccessible*.